# Javascript Anonymous Constructor: is it both an instance and a function? Also, does it leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, constructor, q, anonymous

I've taken to using an instance of an anonymous constructor for the bottom of prototype chains.  This allows me to do weird constructor things like creating closures:

```
var car = new function() {
    var wheels = 4;

    this.getWheels = function() {
        return wheels;
    }
};
```

Now, If I call:

```
console.log(car);
```

the object is logged as expected: `Object { getWheels: car</this.getWheels() }`.  Also, if I call:

```
var toyota = new car();
```

,I receive `TypeError: car is not a constructor`, as expected.  However, if I call:

```
var toyota = new car.Constructor();
```

,I receive a new instance of the anonymous function from earlier.  If fact if I call:

```
console.log(car.constructor);
```

`function car<()` is logged in the console.

First, why is the constructor named `car`, even as the only object it created is also called `car`?  Second, could this be considered to form a memory leak as an anonymous function is saved after it is called?  I'm having a lot of trouble understanding this.  Thank you.

EDIT: I've just found out that this pattern is, indeed, considered to waste memory.  In case anyone was wondering, a more appropriate pattern is the module pattern:

```
var car = function() {
    var wheels = 4;
    return {
        getWheels: function() {return wheels},
    }
}();
```

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the `new` in `var car = new function()`. I am not expert, but I haven't seen it done like that before. I would expect it to be `var car = function()`. Or is this what you mean by "using an instance of anonymous functions"?